# How can I set my include files in clang with c++?

Tags: c++17, clang, llvm

[platform] MacOS M1 Max with llvm installed by homebrew

Homebrew clang version 13.0.1.

Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0.

Thread model: posix.

InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin

xcode-select version 2395.

I do like this:

```
    inline Action * getAction(const string& path)
{

    llvm::LLVMContext *llvmcx;
    static llvm::LLVMContext MyGlobalContext;
    llvmcx = &MyGlobalContext;
    string inputPath = path;


    vector<const char *> args;
    args.push_back(inputPath.c_str());
    
    llvm::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::DiagnosticOptions> opt(new clang::DiagnosticOptions());
    clang::DiagnosticConsumer *client(new DiagnosticConsumer());
    llvm::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::DiagnosticIDs> DiagID(new clang::DiagnosticIDs());
    clang::DiagnosticsEngine * Diags = new DiagnosticsEngine(DiagID, opt, client);

    // Create the compiler invocation
    shared_ptr<clang::CompilerInvocation> CI(new clang::CompilerInvocation());
    clang::CompilerInvocation::CreateFromArgs(*CI, args,*Diags);


    clang::LangOptions * langOptions = new LangOptions();
    langOptions->LangStd = LangStandard::Kind::lang_cxx17;

    clang::FileSystemOptions * fileSystemOptions = new FileSystemOptions();
    clang::FileManager * fileManager = new FileManager(*fileSystemOptions);

    clang::SourceManager * sourceManager = new SourceManager(*Diags,*fileManager);

    shared_ptr<HeaderSearchOptions> headerSearchOptions(new clang::HeaderSearchOptions());
    headerSearchOptions->ResourceDir = "/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm";

    headerSearchOptions->AddPath("/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1", frontend::Angled, false, false);



    auto targetOptions = make_shared<clang::TargetOptions>();
    targetOptions->Triple = llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple();

    clang::TargetInfo * targetInfo = clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(
            *Diags,
            targetOptions
            );

    clang::HeaderSearch headerSearch(
            headerSearchOptions,
            *sourceManager,
            *Diags,
            *langOptions,
            targetInfo
            );


    CI->HeaderSearchOpts = headerSearchOptions;
    
    clang::CompilerInstance Clang;

    Clang.setInvocation(CI);


    Clang.setDiagnostics(Diags);
    Clang.setTarget(targetInfo);
    Clang.setSourceManager(sourceManager);

    Clang.createPreprocessor(clang::TU_Complete);

    Clang.getDiagnostics().setClient(new TextDiagnosticPrinter(llvm::errs(), opt.get()));
    
    if (!Clang.hasDiagnostics())
        return NULL;
    Action *Act = new Action();
    if (!Clang.ExecuteAction(*Act))
    {
        llvm::outs() << Clang.getFrontendOpts().StatsFile;
        Clang.getDiagnostics().getClient()->finish();
        return NULL;
    }

    return Act;
}
```

The parsed file have some includes:

```
#include<iostream>  
#include<vector>  
...(some self-defined headers)
```

but it shows:

```
In file included from /Users/sl/projs/C++_proj/clion/GAMES101/pa6/Ray.hpp:7:
In file included from /Users/sl/projs/C++_proj/clion/GAMES101/pa6/Vector.hpp:8:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:36:
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__config:1151:46: fatal error: cannot open file '/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/pthread.h': No such file or directory
      (defined(__MINGW32__) && __has_include(<pthread.h>))  
                                             ^  

1 error generated.
```

I've tried to add more different header file to "HearderSearchOptions",but it didn't work,it threw some include error different.
I think it's most likely due to the incorrect setting of headersearchoptions,but I'm not so sure.

How to solve it? :-(

Comment: Does the file `/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include/c++/v1/pthread.h` exist? Do you have `pthread.h` installed anywhere else on your computer?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo No. But I changed my include path to another one,it will throw another include error(not <pthread.h>).Is this really just a path issue and not a clang setup issue?

Comment: It's probably a path issue, yes. Did you figure it out? If not, what is the _"other include error"_ you got?